# Water line valve moves into off position but will not turn off

Tags: plumbing, sink, valve, hot-water, shutoff

When I try to research this question it mostly shows valves that are stuck. Mine actually moves into open & closed position but stays fully on.

All the water valves in the house are very hard to move and I'd say this one is still hard but is a bit easier than the rest. I'm not sure if that gives any insight.

Is there some mechanism in the valve that while it still allows for on/off position, it's not latching to the actually mechanism?

[image]

Comment: Do the rest of them shut off the water after 1/4 turn, or do they spin a few revolutions?

Comment: Handles are on valves so we have an easy time to turn the valve itself.  Handles fit on small  round stubs, sometimes square, sometimes spline.  The round stubs work the valve, but are hard to turn with fingers only.

Comment: @AloysiusDefenestrate they all turn off after 1/4 turn

Comment: If you remove the handle, you should be able to operate the valve with vise grips.